# Text will overlap if I use a theme in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I write an app with jetpack compose UI. that is only a Text compose in my screen. But I found that the text will overlap if I use a default theme. How can I Solve this problem？

The UI is like this :

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            CalaulatorTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
              
                Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(MediumGray).padding(16.dp)) {
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .align(Alignment.BottomCenter),
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            text = "12345678901233445568256",
                            textAlign = TextAlign.End,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxSize()
                                .background(Color.Magenta)
                                .padding(vertical = 8.dp),
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Light,
                            fontSize = 60.sp,
                            color = Color.White,
                            maxLines = 2
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the default Theme is like this:

```
@Composable
fun CalaulatorTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    // Dynamic color is available on Android 12+
    dynamicColor: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        }

        darkTheme -> DarkColorScheme
        else -> LightColorScheme
    }
    val view = LocalView.current
    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            (view.context as Activity).window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.primary.toArgb()
            ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(view)?.isAppearanceLightStatusBars = darkTheme
        }
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}
```

But the result is like this:

[image]

Why do the texts overlap with each other？ How should I fix this bug？
if I remove the **"CalaulatorTheme"**, the text display normal.

Answer (score 3):

Just replace your `fontSize = 60.sp` with `style = TextStyle(fontSize = 60.sp)`

[image]

Comment: You're right. It does solve my question, but what causes this?

Comment: Turns out so that the `lineHeight` parameter of the `Text` is set to `24.sp` and layering begins to occur with an increase in `fontSize`